# Positional arguments must occur before named arguments & Too many positional arguments error

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to fix it yet cannot find the solution for these 2 issues:

- Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named)
- Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.dart(positional_after_named_argument)

```
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: phoneController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Phone Number',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
            )
        ),
        onChanged: (value){

        },
      )
  ),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0, bottom: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color:Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                child: const Text(
                  'Save',
                  textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  if(contact == null){
                    // add data
                    contact = Contact(nameController.text,phoneController.text);
                  }else{
                    //edit data
                    contact.name = nameController.text;
                    contact.phone = phoneController.text;
                  }

                  Navigator.pop(context, contact);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(width: 5.0),
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                child: const Text(
                  'Cancel',
                  textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                ),
                onLongPress: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }, onPressed: () {  },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    )
```

Comment: Can you add Contact class in the code?

Comment: Please the entire error message and the code that is mentioned there to your error message, so we can give a concrete answer. However, you should be able to figure it out on your own with the example below.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message gives you already a hint on how to solve it:

```
"Positional arguments must occur before named arguments & Too many positional arguments"
```

**First part: Positional arguments must occur before named arguments**

```
// Where you defined your method
myMethod(positionalParameter1, positionalParameter2, name: namedParameter1) {}

// Where you use it (where the error occurs)
onPressed: myMethod(name: namedParameter1, positionalParameter1, positionalParameter2)

// Solution, assign them in the correct order :)  
onPressed: myMethod(positionalParameter1, positionalParameter2, name: namedParameter1)
```

**Second part: Too many positional arguments**

```
// Where you defined your method
myMethod(positionalParameter1) {}

// Where you use it (where the error occurs)
onPressed: myMethod(positionalParameter1, positionalParameter2)

// Solution: Don´t assign to many parameters or make sure you defined all of them.
```

**FYI: This can also be applied to Classes and their constructor parameters / arguments!**

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same error, I just found out that I didn't close the first Widget before opening another one.